# How do I convert std::chrono::high_resolution type to a float type?

Tags: c++

I want to convert `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock start` to a float type. I tried to use static_cast but I still keep getting a compiling error that says

```
invalid static_cast from type 'std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point {aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >}' to type 'float'
     float duration = static_cast<float>(start) + static_cast<float>(ms);
```

and

```
invalid static_cast from type 'std::chrono::milliseconds {aka std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> >}' to type 'float'
     float duration = static_cast<float>(start) + static_cast<float>(ms);
```

Code:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds ms(5000);
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
float duration = static_cast<float>(start) + static_cast<float>(ms);
```

Comment: I don't know of any standard clock type that could use floats. What is your goal? A work around may have you use `.count()` intead.

Comment: I'm trying to create a timer which sets the duration of the movement of a servo

Comment: What do you want the float to represent? Number of seconds? If so, number of seconds since what?

Comment: i want the float to represent milliseconds and then divide the duration by the incrementing position of the servo so that it moves with the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast `time_point`s like that to get a duration. Try this instead:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

float dur_seconds = std::chrono::duration<float>(end - start).count();
```

If you want to get the duration in something other than seconds, you need to supply the ratio, like `std::milli`:

```
float dur_milli = std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(end - start).count();

std::cout << "time spent: " << dur_seconds << " seconds\n";
std::cout << "time spent: " << dur_milli << " milliseconds\n";
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `duration_cast` to `std::chrono::second` at some point? Is `std::chrono::duration<float>` guaranteed to be in seconds?

Comment: That makes sense. I looked at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) and the template argument `Period` has the default value of `std::ratio<1>`, which represents a duration where the unit is the second.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yepp! To make it a little more complete, I added a ratio example too.